# Create object conditionally

Tags: c#

I would like to know what is the best way to create an object of a certain type depending on a certain condition? At this point, I have an if statement which determines the type of the object that will be instantiated. Now if I have to create another type, this will be a little more complicated. And I would like to know how can this be refactored to work better.

```
public Class1
{
    public string Property1;
}

public Class2 : Class1
{
    public string Property2;
}

public Class3 : Class1
{
    public string Property3;
}

public void Save(string property1)
{
    var object;
    if(property1 == "name")
    {
        object = new Class2();
    }
    else
    {
        object = new Class3();
    }
    // do something with the created object
}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for the Factory Design Pattern https://www.dotnetperls.com/factory

Comment: Also `var object;` is not proper syntax as the compiler cannot determine what the type is and `object` is a reserved word because it is a type alias for `System.Object`. Also where is `property1` coming from? You could do `Class1 myInstance;` and then do the conditional assignment.

Comment: You need factory pattern https://i.imgur.com/NYg3RfD.png

Comment: without knowing what code calls `Save`, this is hard to say... for example, could this be `Save<T>() where T : class, new()` and just use `var obj = new T();`, with the caller doing `Save<Class2>();` ? Otherwise: perhaps a `switch`, or a "switch expression" in C# vNext previews

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below approach using activator.
create  a mapping for class

```
Dictionary<string, string> m_Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();//Dictionary

 m_Dictionary.Add("one", "help.Class1");//Add class name with namespace
 m_Dictionary.Add("two", "help.Class2");
 m_Dictionary.Add("three", "help.Class3");
```

//Change the save method as below

```
    public void Save(string property1)
    {
        dynamic   obj ;

        obj= Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType((m_Dictionary[property1])));

        MessageBox.Show(obj.GetType().ToString());
    }
```

Hope this helps in further refactoring